# Fragments cannot display correctly after clicking back button

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have designed an app which consists of some fragments. The mainscreen, MainScreen consists of a toolbar and a framelayout which displays some tabs and their corresponding fragments.

Layout file for Mainscreen

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<include layout="@layout/toolbar"
/>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/tab_and_view" />
</LinearLayout>
```

For the FrameLayout tab_and_view, the layout is like below

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<com.android.luftschlafer.engdictionary.Tab.SlidingTabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorAccent"/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I used the SlidingTabLayout example from Google to build the tabs.
Then I have designed a page as the homepage, that's called Home_Page. Home_Page has only one ListView item to display some selections and it will be displayed in the ViewPager of MainScreen.

Layout file for Home_Page:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Corr_Pages.HomePage">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/home_function_list"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The codes which handle the swapping in Home_Page.java:

```
FragmentTransaction ftran=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ftran.replace(R.id.tab_and_view,new NewContent());
ftran.addToBackStack("HomePage");
ftran.commit();
```

My design is that when I clicked one item in home_function_list, the fragment will swap to another fragment. For example, from Home_Page to New_Content. 
In New_Content, there is a button which can return of home_page.

In the onClickListener of the button I used these codes to perform the operation.

```
FragmentTransaction ftran=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ftran.replace(R.id.tab_and_view, new TabFragment());
ftran.commit();
```

Refer to [the picture after pressing back button in New_Content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzlcS.png), I found that the contents of Home and Search tabs were missing before i clicked Settings and About App. So I wonder how to let all the contents in the tabs displayed again after I have pressed the "Back" button in New_Content.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a more efficient way, but when I run into this problem with fragments + activities + the back button, I solve it by implementing onBackPressed() in my relevant activities, and within that checking my fragment manager for my back stack. Based on that back stack (which is what allows me to determine from where back was pressed) I am then able to rebuild my UI elements properly. In my case this is important to do this way because I have a toolbar which acts as the apps action bar, and I need to change the appearance of this toolbar as I navigate throughout the app.

So for example what I do is:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mFragManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {

            mFragManager.popBackStack();
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.action_settings);
            getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("");


        } else if (mFragManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            mFragManager.popBackStack();

            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.app_name);
            getSupportActionBar().setIcon(null);

            mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
            statusbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);;

            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);


        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is all assuming that in your main activity somewhere is where the contents of each tab is loaded in.

Comment: In general I think the issue you're facing is you're creating a new Tab Fragment when you click that button in New_Content, which is changing your backstack, when it sounds like what you actually want to do is return to the original home page fragment that should already be in your backstack at that point

Comment: Actually I just want to go back to original home page when I pressed Back, and i am wondering how to do that

Comment: Is that original home page in your fragment back stack? If so I think you can just replicate the behaviour of the actual back button, in popping off your backstack to return to said fragment. You could probably just make the button click call onBackPressed.

Comment: If I use popBackStack, is it possible for onBackPressed to go back to certain Fragment?

Comment: You can use: Fragment currentFragment = MainActivity.mFragManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_frame); to figure out what fragment you're on. You can do this before or after you pop off the back stack, and from there determine if you need to continue popping stacks off or if you're in the right fragment. There is probably a way to traverse the back stack more directly though.

Comment: So to answer your question, yes, you just have to override onBackPressed to navigate to that certain fragment before the super call

Comment: I see. But my thought is that each page is one fragment, so i cannot call onBackPressed in the MainScreen. I am wondering if I can apply the codes of onBackPressed to all fragments

Comment: Well I guess it really depends on how you've set up your greater application; typically when using fragments you would use 1 main activity that the majority of fragments "live" in. As you navigate between fragments, you stay within your main activity but use your fragment manager to navigate between said fragments. In this way, you can utilize separate classes for each fragment, which all have the parent main activity. In onBackPressed in this main activity, you should be able to detect the size or contents of your back stack, and do relevant changes for each fragment as needed

Comment: But note that fragments should do the bulk of/all UI changes they are responsible for. I typically only use the strategy I'm outlining to return my UI to the state it was in when main activity was first created, after I've navigated to other fragments and back. Since the Main Activity is almost never re-created by virtue of always being active, when any UI changes to it that need to be reverted, I've always done in onBackPressed.

Comment: Good,thanks for help! I found it was very difficult so I decided to build a new activity when i click the corresponding options.